# 2 buttons one has extra features

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, html

I have two different buttons. Both of which when clicked runs the JQuery function 'ShowCommentBox'
However when the second button is clicked I want to load an additional JQuery function along 'SHowCommentBox' - the additional function allowing extra options on screen.

```
<input id="SubmitCommentsForBOQ" type="button" value="Comments" onclick="ShowCommentBox('<%: item.ItemCode %>'')" />
```

Above is the second button I want to also run the

```
 $("#SubmitCommentsForTwo").click(function () {
        $("#hiddenBox").show();
    });
```

, which makes the extra features visible...how can I do this?

Thank you for any replies

Below is the original JQuery: which loads a dialogue box

```
function ShowCommentBox(itemIdentifier, labourOrPlant, desc) {
        id = itemIdentifier;
        LabouringOrPlanting = labourOrPlant;
        description = desc;
        Function.DisplayBox(itemIdentifier);
        $("#LabourOrPlantDialog").dialog({ modal: true }); 
    }
```

and my other code:

```
    <div id="LabourOrPlantDialog" title="Comments"  style="display:none;">
 <table class="detailstable FadeOutOnEdit">
     <tr>
        <th>Item</th>
     </tr>
     <tr>
         <td id="Item"></td>
     </tr>
 </table>    
 <br />

       <textarea id="ExistingComments" type="text" runat="server" rows="7" cols="30"
        maxlength="2000"> </textarea> 
       <input id="SubmitComment" type="button" value="Submit"
            onclick="SubmitButton()" />  

<br />

<div id="hiddenBox">
<input type="text" name="BoqTextBox" id="BoqTextBox" value="7.15" />
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: If you have two different buttons, why aren't you just changing the onclick function for the second button? They are two seperate DOM elements, correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's best to [separate behavior from markup](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unobtrusive_JavaScript). You can solve both problems using an HTML `data-` attribute.

First embed the data in the HTML:

```
<input id="SubmitCommentsForBOQ" type="button" value="Comments"
    data-item-code="<%: item.ItemCode %>" />
```

Instead of `onclick`, bind the event handler using jQuery only, and perform all the actions you need at once:

```
$("#SubmitCommentsForBOQ").click(function () {
    var itemCode = $(this).data('itemCode');
    ShowCommentBox(itemCode);
});

$("#SubmitCommentsForTwo").click(function () {
    $("#hiddenBox").show();
    var itemCode = $(this).data('itemCode');
    ShowCommentBox(itemCode);
});
```

Multiple handlers will execute in the order in which they are bound, so you could also do something like this:

```
// happens first, but only for this specific button
$("#SubmitCommentsForTwo").click(function () {
    $("#hiddenBox").show();
});

// happens for all buttons
$("input[data-item-code]").click(function () {
    var itemCode = $(this).data('itemCode');
    ShowCommentBox(itemCode);
});
```